# Request body gets lost in http get request. (Java-Spark)

Tags: java, spark-java

When I sent the following request to my program, the body gets lost:

```
GET http://localhost:4567/contacts/get-all

Authorization : test
Content-Type : text/plain

Hello
```

Java Code

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Spark.get("contacts/get-all", (request, response) -> {
            checkForAuth(request);
            if (request != null) {
                System.out.println(request.body());
            }
            return "Success";
        });
    }

    protected static void checkForAuth(Request request) {
        if (request != null) {
            String authorization = request.headers("Authorization");
            System.out.println(authorization);
            if ("test".equals(authorization))
                return;
        }
        throw new Error("Not Authorized.");
    }
}
```

I expected the sysout to print Hello, but it only prints test (authorization header).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: Don't use GET for request bodies.

Comment: So if I want to filter the results of the request I have to use queries?

Comment: @xtay2 You could use a query parameter. Or you could use POST.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [documentation](https://sparkjava.com/documentation#routes), you need to use `*` or `:` to make your request `non-null` e.g. :

```
Spark.get("contacts/:get-all", (request, response) -> {
            checkForAuth(request);
            if (request != null) {
                System.out.println(request.body());
            }
            return "Success";
        });
```

OR

```
Spark.get("contacts/*", (request, response) -> {
            checkForAuth(request);
            if (request != null) {
                System.out.println(request.body());
            }
            return "Success";
        });
```

& then call:

```
GET http://localhost:4567/contacts/get-all
```

This will print :

> get-all

If you want to print, Hello, you have to append `Hello` to your get request.

Currently, it looks like request is coming as null & hence skipping executing `System.out.println(request.body());`